# Extracting first word of line with regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this block of text:

```
XQuery programming language
C# programming language
declarative programming
XSLT programming language
Haskell programming language vs F* programming language
```

I want to retrieve the names of the programming languages.

I tried something like

```
matches = string.scan('/(\w)*\sprogramming language/i')
```

But that gives me this:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Whereas I want an array like this:

```
['XQuerye','C#','XSLT','Haskell']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must need to remove the quotes around the regex delimiter `/`

```
string.scan(/\S+(?=\sprogramming language)/i)
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. `(?=\sprogramming language)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a space and a `programming language` string. `i` modifier makes the regex engine to do a case-insensitive match.

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/y2BvOk3Rap)

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "XQuery programming language
irb(main):002:0" C# programming language
irb(main):003:0" declarative programming
irb(main):004:0" XSLT programming language
irb(main):005:0" Haskell programming language vs F* programming language"
=> "XQuery programming language\nC# programming language\ndeclarative programming\nXSLT programming language\nHaskell programming language vs F* programming language"
irb(main):007:0> str.scan(/\S+(?=\sprogramming language)/i)
=> ["XQuery", "C#", "XSLT", "Haskell", "F*"]
```

Comment: thanks, that was it :) (also the asterisk * was at wrong place, thanks for hinting me at this)

Comment: use ` ` instead of `\s` if necessary because `\s` would match also the line breaks. And note that i used `\S+` instead of `\w+` because `\w+` won't match the `#` symbol in `C#`

Comment: thanks for the great explaining answer. also i didn't know about rubular. thx!

Comment: Avinash, evidently F* is not wanted. I was confused by your first line, because in the following you use a positive lookahead, whereas the OP used a capture group.  No problem using a positive lookahead, of course; it just came as a surprise.  In fact, after reading just your first line, I assumed you were keeping the capture group, so I decided to write an answer that used a postive lookahead. Only later did I read your answer fully, so then I went back and changed my answer to use a capture group. No regrets; it was good practice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need only make a couple of small changes to what you have. I've assumed the text you want always starts at the beginning of a line (because you've excluded `'F*'`) and is separated from `"programming language"`by one or more spaces.

```
text =<<_
XQuery programming language
C# programming language
declarative programming
XSLT programming language
Haskell programming language vs F* programming language
_

text.scan(/(^.+?)\s+programming language/i).flatten
  #=> ["XQuery", "C#", "XSLT", "Haskell"]
```

Notes:

- `^` in the regex is the beginning-of-line anchor. It needs to be inside the capture group `(^.+)`. If we had `^(.+)`, `nil` would be returned by `scan` for the third line.
- The first `?` in the regex makes `.+` "non-greedy". Without it, the last element of the array returned would be:

  "Haskell programming language vs F*"

- In problems like this one you often have the choice between using a capture group (as here) or a lookaround (as @AvinashRaj did in his answer).

Comment: the reason why i choose  lookaround instead of capturing groups means, output would be an multidimensional array if we use capturing group. So we need an extra flatten function. This would be avoided when using lookarounds.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, I noticed that, but I'd be surprised if it makes much difference efficiency-wise.